rdfref, lualatex, dot2tex, --shell-escape works, but not with --output-dir
A new latex pkg is developped in rdfref
I copy a MWE (using that package sorry)
What works:
lualatex --shell-escape mwe.tex


What does not work:
lualatex --shell-escape --output-dir=build mwe.tex  

The dot file is generated in the build directory but somehow not used in the construction of the pdf.
The relevant rdfref code is this
\NewDocumentCommand\RdfDrawGraph{O{\jobname-graph} O{rdfs:label} m m}{%
  \immediate\openout\rdf@graphwrite=#1.dot\relax%
  \rdf@graphout{digraph hello\@charlb} % save graph header
  \RdfLoopReferences{#3}{#4}{%
    \edef\objectlabel{\currentobject}%
    \edef\subjectlabel{\currentsubject}%
    \regex_replace_all:nnN{[:\-]}{_}\objectlabel%
    \regex_replace_all:nnN{[:\-]}{_}\subjectlabel%
    \rdf@graphout{\objectlabel [shape="rectangle",texlbl="\GetProperty{\currentobject}{#2}"]}
    \rdf@graphout{\subjectlabel [shape="rectangle",texlbl="\GetProperty{\currentsubject}{#2}"]}
    \rdf@graphout{\objectlabel~->~\subjectlabel} %
  }
  \rdf@graphout{\@charrb}% save footer
  \immediate\closeout\rdf@graphwrite%
  \ShellEscape{dot2tex~--figonly~--autosize~-t~raw~-o~#1.tmp~#1.dot }%
  \IfFileExists{#1.tmp}{\input{#1.tmp}}{}%
}

so the rdfref author proposed the following change
\def\BuildDir{build/}
\NewDocumentCommand\RdfDrawGraph{O{\jobname-graph} O{rdfs:label} m m}{%
  \immediate\openout\graphwrite=#1.dot\relax%
  \graphout{digraph hello\@charlb} % save graph header
  \RdfLoopReferences{#3}{#4}{%
    \StrSubstitute{\currentobject}{:}{_}[\objectlabel]
    \StrSubstitute{\currentsubject}{:}{_}[\subjectlabel]
    \graphout{\objectlabel [shape="rectangle",texlbl="\GetProperty{\currentobject}{#2}"]}
    \graphout{\subjectlabel [shape="rectangle",texlbl="\GetProperty{\currentsubject}{#2}"]}
    \graphout{\objectlabel-> \subjectlabel} %
  }
  \graphout{\@charrb}% save footer
  \immediate\closeout\graphwrite%
  \ShellEscape{dot2tex --figonly --autosize -t raw -o \BuildDir#1.tmp \BuildDir#1.dot }%
  \InputIfFileExists{#1.tmp}{}%
}

but this leads to an error
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! I can't write on file `build/mwe-graph.dot'.

any help would be appreciated

--output-dir  complicates every tex pipeline, you tell tex to hide its output somewhere then you have to configure every  related program to find the hidden files.

well the general advice is not to use --output-dir. You can spent lots of time trying to debug such problems.

does your build directory exist? why can't tex write to it?  But in general the best solution to any output-dir issue is not to use that option.

yes the output-dir exists, I find it convenient to have all these aux files etc in separate directory, it keeps the main directory tidy, but if you advise against it.......

you can always move the files in whatever script or editor pipeline,  that is do the entire job in the build directory and then just copy the pdf to a final "clean" location if you need that. but the scratch directory I use for answering questions here currently has over a thousand log files, why does it matter? I clean it up every now and then, but mostly I just leave them around,

Well I use GNU emacs, who supports --output-dir nicely, besides I use subfiles or xr-hyper quite a bit, so I want in my main directory just these TeX files, and all the other stuff in the build. So in this particular use case I might be forced to use some script to keep my directory tidy.

You might want to try using latexmk to compile your document, configuring it to use dot2tex, without the need to use --shell-escape. There's an file dot2tex-latexmkrc in the latexmk distribution that shows how to do this. The last I tried, it worked correctly with --output-directory option.

Hi thanks, this sounds very useful, can you give me a pointer please.
https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/dot2tex-latexmkrc seems not the official one

Ok I downloaded from CTAN latexmk and found that file, I used latexmf only occasionally so any pointer of how to use this dot2tex-latexmkrc would be appreciated.

To use the code in dot2tex-latexmkrc, make a file latexmkrc in the same directory as the document.  Then copy the code from dot2tex-latexmkrc into latexmkrc.   Then just run latexmk -pdflua --output-dir=build mwe.tex.   (Later you can add code to latexmkrc to configure the use of lualatex and the output directory without the need for the command-line options.)

Thanks, but I obtain the following error:
latexmk -pdflua --output-dir=build mwe.tex Latexmk: -output-dir=build unknown option Rc files read:   /etc/LatexMk   latexmkrc Latexmk: Bad options specified Use    latexmk -help to get usage information 
also latexmk -help shows me that --output-dir is a valid option
-output-directory=dir or -outdir=dir                   - set name of directory for output files
any idea what is wrong?
